Is there a way to automatically update Azure Repo when changes are made?
Basically, developers in my organization commit changes on local SVN repo and they want to be able to automatically update Azure repo without having to go on Azure repo or some other software or command line each time.
In order to solve this problem, I tried to understand Azure Pipelines, but I don't think there is a Pipeline command that does this.
Edit: If this doesn't work on SVN, would it work on a local Git repo?

What's a "local SVN repo" as opposed to an "Azure repo"? Subversion is a centralized VCS, there is only one repo. Please [edit] and clarify what you're trying to do. Hook scripts would be a way to trigger a pipeline on a commit. The other way would be polling the repo.

@Friedrich
There being one repo does not mean any repo changes made can't be updated onto Azure repo though. Can't Azure repo create a copy and migrate those changes?

Are you perhaps confusing repositories with working copies?
